# Detecting when a button is touched in SKScene?

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit, skscene

I created a storyboard and added a scene with two buttons. I cannot figure out how to know when a button is pressed on my GameScene.swift class.

How can this be done?

[image]

Comment: You can use a component like https://github.com/akashgupta88/AGSpriteButton. It lets you perform operations for various touch events.

Comment: Are these actual uibuttons or nodes you're using as buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be mixing UIKit and SpriteKit here. I would personally advise against using UIButtons in conjunction with Sprite Kit. Is there a specific reason for doing so?

There are two ways you can implement button behavior within a Sprite Kit scene:

1. have the SKScene object handle the touches
2. have the button itself handle the touches

Dharmesh's answer uses method (1), where he implements the `-touchesBegan` method. 
In my current project, I am using an SKNode subclass as a button (2). I am unfamiliar with Swift syntax so I have posted Objective-C code from my project instead. The method calls are similar though and should help illustrate the point.

**If you want an SKNode to receive touches, set `userInteractionEnabled` to `YES`.** Otherwise, the closest ancestor with `userInteractionEnabled = YES` (which typically is the containing SKScene) will receive a `-touchesBegan`/`-touchesMoved`/`-touchesEnded` message.

```
@interface VTObject : SKNode

@end

...

@implementation VTObject

- (instancetype)init {     
  if (self = [super init]) {
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
  }

  return self;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {    
  NSLog(@"button touched!");
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can you `touchesBegan` for that.

Here is example code for you:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    for touch: AnyObject in touches{
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.playButton{

              //your code
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `UIButton` programatically, instead of in IB, to the `SKScene`'s `SKView` (in `didMoveToView` for example). You can then set the target for the button with `button.addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`. Just remember to call `button.removeFromSuperview()` in `willMoveFromView` otherwise you'll see the buttons in your next scene.